# OneTimeSetUp: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, nunit, devops

I have a regression test that test multiple scenarios using NUnit and it's running via Azure Pipeline and each scenario have [OneTimeSetup] and [OneTimeTeardown]

The error I'm getting is the title itself
I suspect the Azure Pipeline can't handle many scenarios that's why it's failing

What I did so far is this

```
foreach (string file_path in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetTempPath().ToString(), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
  try {
    FileInfo current_file = new FileInfo(file_path);
    current_file.Delete();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Error on file: {0}\r\n   {1}", file_path, e.Message);
  }
}
```

What this lines of code doing is deleting all temp files in Azure pipeline and I included it in [OneTimeSetup] so it will be executed once new scenario is executed.

But after 2 hours of running it's still failing, Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To optimize memory use, try using `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`. Also you do not need to create `FileInfo` object, but just use static delete method of `File`.

> The
> [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles)
> and
> [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles)
> methods differ as follows:
>
> - When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is
>   returned.
> - When you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array.
>
> Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories,
> EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

```cs
foreach (string file_path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetTempPath().ToString(), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
  try {
    File.Delete(file_path);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Error on file: {0}\r\n   {1}", file_path, e.Message);
  }
}
```

You can also consider using the overload which accepts `EnumerationOptions` where you can set suggested buffer size low to reduce memory use.

Comment: Great! Appreciate it, thanks for the idea will try to do this and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still replicating the issue. Thanks for the answer @krishg